# How do i resolve an expected class, delegate, enum, interface, struct compiling error?

Tags: c#

I am getting this error at private void ...

This a real simple program that I want to display a message using a string variable.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        {
            string greetme;
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            greetme = textbox1.text;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello {0}", greetme);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect `{ string greetme; }` to do? Why do you have the braces?

Comment: As the compiler is trying to tell you, your code (in particular, those braces) doesn't make sense .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the parenthesis around your declaration of `greetme`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string greetme;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        greetme = textbox1.text;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello {0}", greetme);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors almost always mean that you have brackets where you shouldn't.  In this situation, it's the brackets/code after your "Public Form1()" method.  There is no method declaration and no need for brackets there.